# Optimal Point Coverage by 2 disks

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a point set S, it is required to cover the maximum number of points using 2 circles of fixed radius r. The maximum number of points that can be covered by one disk can be computed by considering every pair of points with distance less than 2r. 2 circles can be possibly constructed passing through one pair of points. From all such combinations, the circle covering the maximum points and the circle covering the second maximum points are selected. But will it give the optimal answer or is there some changes to be made in this method?

Answer (score 0):

A version of your problem is called
the *two center problem* for points: Given a set *P* of *n* points in
the plane, find two smallest congruent disks that cover
all points in *P*.
Often a subpart of this problem is to solve it for a fixed radius *r*, which is your problem. If you draw circles of radius *r* about each point, you want to
"pierce" the two deepest cells of the arrangement.

Here's one relatively recent paper that should allow you to search back through the literature:

> Ahn, Hee-Kap, Sang-Sub Kim, Christian Knauer, Lena Schlipf, Chan-Su Shin, and Antoine Vigneron. "Covering and piercing disks with two centers." *Computational Geometry* 46, no. 3 (2013): 253-262.